# Como colocar border-radius numa iframe maps?

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma iframe com o mapa do google eu queria colocar um `border-radius` para obter cantos arredondados tentei `border-radius` mas não deu alguma sugestão como posso fazer isso?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/56Vbp/ Aqui tem um exemplo.... que veio dessa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610093/giving-an-iframe-a-border-radius

Comment: esse exemplo tive a ver não fica com os cantos arredondados

Comment: Colocasse uma div ao redor da iframe como mostra o exemplo?

Comment: sim mas nesse exemplo se repares o mapa não fica com os cantos arredondados

Comment: Aqui está arredondado... '.'

Comment: Aqui não ainda tive a ver agora

Comment: já sei é por causa do safari

Comment: É que testei no chrome e firefox e estavam funcionando perfeitamente...

Comment: sim já vi que funciona eu e que estava no safari

Comment: marque a sugestão como resposta

Comment: Em resumo, diretamente no iframe parece não funcionar, você precisa embrulhá-lo em uma div com o `border-radius` (+ variantes cross-browser, prefixadas).

Comment: Bem já consegui resolver obrigado pela ajuda de todos

Comment: Usei -webkit-border-radius: 15px; para o safari mas mesmo assim não me funciona

Comment: @CésarSousa para o safari, tente a seguinte solução: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Answer (score 1):

É só usar o `border-radius` mesmo, porém num `span` por fora do iframe:

HTML:

```
<span id="mapa">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d12242.306455925878!2d-75.12138282383809!3d39.90611059880662!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x3e48fdca1ebac4d0!2sWalt+Whitman+Bridge!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1395728987250" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#mapa {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Isso deve funcionar. Caso pra você ainda não apareça com os cantos arredondados, pode ser questão de compatibilidade de browser quanto à propriedade `border-radius`, tenta adicionar o seguinte:

```
#mapa {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%; /* CSS3 */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */  
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```